# Set variable if input field contains text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search box with an icon which slides to the right if the input field is focused.
I use `ng-focus` and `ng-blur`to set the active state of the icon. If the input field contains a text, the icon should have the active state. How do you achieve this the angular way?

```
<div class="search">
    <label for="search_users" style="background-image: url('assets/img/search_big.png')" ng-class="{ active: uFocus }"></label>
    <input id="search_users" ng-model="user_query" ng-focus="uFocus=true" ng-blur="uFocus=false">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expressions in ng-class for example

```
ng-class="{ 'active': (uFocus || user_query.length>0) }"
```

This will add the `active` class to your input in case of it is focus, or the user enter any input

**You can see a working example of it:**

```js
angular.module('app',[])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .active{
    background-color:blue
      }
  </style>
<div ng-app="app">
<label ng-class="{active:user_query.length>0 || isfocus}">The Label</label>
<input ng-model=user_query ng-focus="isfocus=true" ng-blur="isfocus=false">
  {{user_query}}
</div>
```